# Can 'ArgumentResolver' be used continuously on Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to use continuously annotations with `ArgumentResolver` in the controller.
But `ArgumentResolver` is always returning objects.

What I want is `AdminUserArgumentResolver` to be an `ArgumentResolver` that verifies whether it is a manager.

`LoginUserArgumentResolv`er wants to do a logic of finding members through tokens.

Two annotations are returning the Object. There seems to be a problem here.

Couldn't we, like `@Valid` Annotation, put up a series of annotations about Argument?
For example, `public method(@Valid @RequestBody RequestDto requestDto)`

```java
// AdminUserArgumentResolver.class
@Component
public class AdminUserArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(AdminUser.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
        NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
        String role = (String)webRequest.getAttribute("role", SCOPE_REQUEST);

        if (!Objects.equals(role, Role.ADMIN.name())) {
            throw new InvalidAuthorizationException();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```java
// LoginUserArgumentResolver.class
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LoginUserArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    private final UserService userService;

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(LoginUser.class);
    }

    @Override
    public User resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
        NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
        String userId = (String)webRequest.getAttribute("userId", SCOPE_REQUEST);

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(userId)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        try {
            return userService.findById(Long.parseLong(userId));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
//controller
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> save(
        @AdminUser @LoginUser User user,  // I want to do this.
        @Valid @RequestBody NoticeCreateRequest request
    ) {
        Long noticeId = noticeService.save(request);
        return ResponseEntity
            .created(URI.create(String.format("/api/notices/%d", noticeId)))
            .build();
    }
```

I want to know the keywords related to it. Thank you.

Comment: An argument resolver is that an argument resolver. Don't mix responsibilities. If you want security then implement security (you probably should be using Spring Security instead of inventing your own security framework).